# Is there a way to resolve OptimisticLockingFailureException in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch configuration as such.

```
@Bean(BatchJobConstant.WITHDRAW_BATCH_JOB)
    public Job importJob(@Qualifier(BatchJobConstant.CUSTOM_READER) CustomListItemReader<WithdrawDetails> reader,
                         @Qualifier(BatchJobConstant.CUSTOM_WRITER) ItemWriter<WithdrawDetails> writer,
                         @Qualifier(BatchJobConstant.CUSTOM_PROCESSOR) ItemProcessor<WithdrawDetails,
                                 WithdrawDetails> processor,
                         @Qualifier(BatchJobConstant.POOL_TASK_EXECUTOR) TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        final Step writeToDatabase = stepBuilderFactory.get(BatchJobConstant.WITHDRAW_BATCH_STEP)
                .<WithdrawDetails, WithdrawDetails>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                .throttleLimit(throttleLimit)
                .build();

        return jobBuilderFactory.get(BatchJobConstant.WITHDRAW_JOB_BUILDER_FACTORY)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(writeToDatabase)
                .build();
    }
```

The custom reader is as:

```
public class CustomListItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<T> list) {
        log.debug("Set list of size {}", list.size());
        if (AopUtils.isAopProxy(list)) {
            this.list = list;
        } else {
            this.list = new ArrayList<T>(list);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized T read() {
        log.debug("Inside custom list item reader");
        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("Inside read not empty");
            T remove = list.remove(0);
            while (remove == null && !list.isEmpty()) {
                remove = list.remove(0);
            }
            return remove;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when there is a huge number of data. The

> org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=XXX with wrong version (X), where current version is Y

exception occurs. I have tried debugging by using various methods:

1. I checked whether multiple batch jobs were running concurrently on the same database. This was not the case, only a single batch job was running.
2. I constructed a NoOpProcessor and a NoOpWriter. I adjusted the job and it worked well.
   From this, I found that the problem was in the processor as the NoOpProcessor was working really well.
   But, the question I have is, my original processor is as such:

   ```
    @Override
    public WithdrawDetails process(WithdrawDetails details) throws Exception {
        try {
              return withdrawService.performMerchantAutoWithdraw(details);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occurred. Error: {}", e.getMessage());
            details.setWithdrawStatus(WithdrawStatus.FAILED);
            details.setFailedReason(e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("INSIDE PROCESSOR :{}", details.getId());
        return details;
    }
   ```

I am catching a generic Exception, and when I checked my logs. I found the **INSIDE PROCESSOR** log printed every time. So, how is it that when the Spring batch tries to save after the commit interval the Locking Exception occurs? Is it due to the parallel processing?

I tried printing every **TRACE** log from spring batch. But I only got these

```
"org.springframework.batch.core.step.FatalStepExecutionException: JobRepository failure forcing rollback
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:464)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:871)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:708)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy297.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor403.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:19"
```

AND

```
10:40:19.339 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3064
10:40:19.671 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3065
10:40:19.871 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3066
10:40:20.067 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3067
10:40:20.232 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3068
10:40:20.325 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3070
10:40:20.563 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3072
10:40:20.800 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3073
10:40:21.100 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3074
10:40:21.138 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - INSIDE PROCESSOR :3076
10:40:21.138 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - Updating merchant auto withdraw details.
10:40:21.138 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  com.test.batchJob - IDS FOR WRITER :[3064, 3065, 3066, 3067, 3068, 3070, 3072, 3073, 3074, 3076] 
10:40:21.138 [async-task-exec-11] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet - Inputs not busy, ended: false
10:40:21.187 [async-task-exec-11] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=10, written=10, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
10:40:21.193 [async-task-exec-11] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=4615, version=1, name=merchantAutoWithdraw, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=70, filterCount=0, writeCount=10 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=1, exitDescription=
10:40:21.198 [async-task-exec-11] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - JobRepository failure forcing rollback
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=4615 with wrong version (1), where current version is 6
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao.updateStepExecution(JdbcStepExecutionDao.java:279)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy294.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy294.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:457)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:40:21.199 [async-task-exec-11] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Rollback for RuntimeException: org.springframework.batch.core.step.FatalStepExecutionException: JobRepository failure forcing rollback
10:40:21.200 [async-task-exec-11] INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
```

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1826. But I'm curious to understand your case better in case it helps in solving the issue. Is the service `withdrawService.performMerchantAutoWithdraw` you use in your item processor transactional? ie is it running in a nested transaction or within the scope of the same transaction driven by the step? I'm asking because you said the issue does not happen with a `NoOpItemProcessor`.

Comment: No, the method performMerchantAutoWithdraw is not Transactional. But some of the queries inside it are (short queries) and many REST API calls are present. Can it be due to the transaction manager in the configuration?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely related to transactions. `No, the method performMerchantAutoWithdraw is not Transactional. But some of the queries inside it are (short queries)`: this means there are ongoing transactions behind this method, and this is what I was referring to in my previous comment. Can you share which transaction propagation these transactions are using (`REQUIRES_NEW`, `NESTED`, etc)? This is key to answer your question.

Comment: `REQUIRES_NEW` is the one that's used, deep inside the method.

Comment: I removed the `REQUIRES_NEW` from my code, it started working. But is there a specific reason why the Spring batch behaves this way? Because I believe, even though a new transaction has started, the Spring Batch's transaction will be suspended for a certain time. But, later the application uses the same transaction of Spring Batch. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: `is there a specific reason why the Spring batch behaves this way`: The transaction management itself is out of control of Spring Batch, it is rather handled by Spring Framework. What Spring Batch does is run your tasklet step in a transaction and allows you to customize the attributes of that transaction.

Comment: I am still unable to understand the cause of the exception. I know that Sprint Batch uses a transaction for each chunk. And any exception thrown from the item processor or the item writer triggers a rollback. But I have caught all the exceptions in the processor. In the Spring batch in Action (Manning), It's written that REQUIRES_NEW causes problem as it interferes with Spring Batch's transaction. But I am unable to get how the optimistic locking occurs due to this.